# How to have internal links for sections get redirected from another page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a webstite and it's going great, but I on one of my pages, it has multiple sections such as `about us` and `contact us` and I have internal links sorted to an extent where it does go to that section from another page, but all the drop down menu items are highlighted.

What I did first was give the headers an `id` so for exampe `<h3 id="aboutus">` and in the menu item, I did `#aboutus` which worked when I was on the page but not when I wasn't, so I changed the menu item so that it included the `url` for that page which is now `www.website.co.uk/about-us/#aboutus` which causes all the drop down menu items to get highlighted.

How would I change what I have so that if I'm on, lets say, the home page and click on `about us`, it directs me to that section without the whole drop down menu being highlighted?

**Edit**

The menus and drop down menus are provided in a plugin in WordPress

**Edit 2**

The code I have in the `about` page is `<h3 id=aboutus>About Us</h3>` and the menus are automatically given as part of a plugin on WordPress.

Comment: You'll have to add some more information here. How are you making these drop down menus?

Comment: @ArneBrasseur I'm using a plugin on WordPress that makes the basic template which includes the menus

Comment: @ArneBrasseur But I can change the URL which each menu item points to

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)